# Get current location of user

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been looking for this but cannot find anything that is actually working. I'm trying to get the current position(longitude and latitude) in the "onMapReady" method. But it does not seem to work. I'm using the **Google Maps Directions API** and I want it to move the "position" when the user starts moving. (But I need the current location in the onMapsReady to insert it into a start position)

I've started to add this:

```
Location location;

     @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        double lon = location.getLongitude();
        double lat = location.getLatitude();

        System.out.println(lon + "," + lat);

        //Adding markers in the map.
        mMap.addMarker(place1);
        mMap.addMarker(place2);


    }
```

So how can I get the current position of a user in the onMapReady method? And then keep it moving when the user drives away? Do you know how to fix this? What do I need to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using GPS library. Am not an android developer​ but I'm sure there should be a GPS library which you could use to get the user current geo location

Comment: @myckhel How can I access that?

Comment: You can search on Google​ . Maybe android gps library. Something like that

Comment: @myckhel yep, ofc. Just wanted to check if you had one in ur mind. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully someone​ that has the GPS experience would let you know.

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move the camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapLocationActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like it is outdated. Do you use this or na?